# How do I call a variable in another method?

Tags: java, variables, methods, scope

I know that the variable maxreps isn't in the scope of my main method so I wanted it call it by creating an object, but it still isn't able to get maxreps.
How could I fix this?

```
public class LUIS{
    public void james(){
        int current=1;
        int maxreps=1;

        String adriana = "aabbddddnsspkrrgg";
        for(int a=0; a<adriana.length(); a++){
            if(adriana.charAt(a) == adriana.charAt(a+1)){
                current++;
                if(maxreps>=current){
                    maxreps=current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        public static void main(String[] args){
        LUIS fritz = new LUIS();
        final int drei = fritz.james;

        System.out.println(maxreps);
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare "int maxreps = 1" as a class variable, put it before the james() method.

Comment: But then I get an error that the main moethod can't use non-static variables.

Comment: "How do I call a variable in another method?" you don't, that is why it is called *local* variable because its scope is limited to code block (method) in which it was declared. If you need variable which will be available for all methods make it class field. But are you sure you want variable and not its value? If it is value you want to get then maybe let your method return it.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, scoping prevents seeing a variable defined in a different scope. You can resolve your particular issue by returning the value

```
public int james(){  // <-- change from void to an int return
    int current=1;
    int maxreps=1;

    String adriana = "aabbddddnsspkrrgg";
    for(int a=0; a<adriana.length(); a++){
        if(adriana.charAt(a) == adriana.charAt(a+1)){
            current++;
            if(maxreps>=current){
                maxreps=current;
            }
        }
    }

    return maxreps;  // <-- return the value
}
```

And then in the `main` method set a variable to the returned value.

Alternatively, you can define it as a class variable, but there are reasons to avoid doing so -- globals are generally bad.

Comment: @LuisIsLuis, if by "doesn't work" you mean it the program doesn't achieve your expected output, you should realize there are potentially other logic errors. Doesn't work isn't exactly a helpful description. However, your loop check is wrong (if you do `adriana.length` then you cannot do `.charAt(a+1)` due to array overflow). You really should pose a new question, with updated method and variable names, and this *specific* question was about variable scoping.

Answer (score 2):

1)   `final int drei = fritz.james;` cannot compile. You cannot invoke a method in this way (that is without `()`).

2) Besides, the `james()` method should have a more meaningful name.
This method computes the max series of a same character. So, you could call it `computeMaxSeries()`

3) And instead being a void method, you could return the max series number.

4) Besides this :

```
    for (int a = 0; a < adriana.length(); a++) {
        if (adriana.charAt(a) == adriana.charAt(a + 1)) {
```

will throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` as `adriana.charAt(a + 1)` refers to an index beyond the valid limit of the String length.
You should rather iterate until the last index -1  :

```
for (int a = 0; a < adriana.length()-1; a++) {
```

5) At last this is not consistent since you update `maxreps` by relying on `maxreps` instead of `current` :

```
if(maxreps>=current){
   maxreps=current;
}
```

You should rather write :

```
if (current >= maxreps) {
    maxreps = current;
}
```

So, finally the method would be :

```
public int computeMaxSeries(){
    int current=1;
    int maxreps=1;

    String adriana = "aabbddddnsspkrrgg";
    for(int a=0; a<adriana.length()-1; a++){
        if(adriana.charAt(a) == adriana.charAt(a+1)){
            current++;
            if (current >= maxreps) {
               maxreps = current;
            }   
        }
    }
   return maxreps;
}
```

Now you can do :

```
    final int maxreps = fritz.computeMaxSeries();
    System.out.println(maxreps);
```

Comment: `
    public int computeMaxSeries(){
        int current=1;
        int maxreps=1;
        
        String adriana = "abbc";
        for(int a=0; a<adriana.length(); a++){
            if(adriana.charAt(a) == adriana.charAt(a+1)){
                current++;
                if(maxreps>=current){
                    maxreps=current;
                }
            }
        }
        return maxreps;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LUIS dr = new LUIS();
        final int maxreps = dr.computeMaxSeries();
        System.out.println(maxreps);
    }
}
`

Comment: I simply copied your code, but it now only prints out 1(the digit 1).